# Hardware troubleshooting

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there an existing Stack Exchange site where it would be appropriate to get some thoughts about trouble shooting problems with computers/computer hardware (in general terms?). Kind of a Stack Exchange equivalent of `TomsHardware.com` or similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sounds like what [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) is for.

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - personal and home computer networking

Comment: Ah yeah sounds about right. I had always assumed it was more software oriented. Maybe Super User is just a misleading name to me. Thanks!